# CRM 2011 Development toolkit

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I just installed the CRM Development Toolkit and everything seems to be working fine until I need to deploy the plugins. According to the tutorials I should have a **Deploy** option just below **Rebuild** when i right click on the project package(in this case **Lan2Lan**). Unfortunately I have no such option.
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to deploy in this manner, create your initial project using the Solution Template rather than the individual plug-in library template. It will create projects for plug-ins, workflows and SilverLight. You can delete the projects you don't need. In the end you should have a project called 'CrmPackage' which you can right click on and have a 'Deploy' option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that if all you are maintaining is JScript, then use the CRM 2011 Package project.  It doesn't create the Plugin, WF and Silverlight projects - which have to be compiled and deployed slowing down your deploys.

Personally, I keep my web resources and compiled projects in separate projects to speed my JScript develop/debug/deploy process.

Comment: According to his question he is creating a plugin.

Comment: yes i already created the plugins though... ill just have to import them here again :P thx anyways :)